Is there a way in python to generate a QR-code image with text (preferably it's content) underneath?
I'm currently working on a small database in which I can put plants with different properties. To ease the finding of the plants, I plan on generating QR codes to go on the pots. I want to create an image of the QR code with its content underneath (plant ID number in this case). Is there a way to do this?
I'm using Tkinter and SQlite3 for my database. This is the code I got so far. It generates a normal QR code without text:
import qrcode

def qr():
    selected_item = tree.focus()
    if not selected_item:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Choose a plant to generate a qr-code for")
    else:
        qr = plant_id_entry.get()
        img = qrcode.make(qr)
        type(img)
        img.save(f"{qr} {date.today()}.png")
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "A qr-code has been generated")

I've tried googling the problem but nothing seemed to pop up, only recommendations about logos in the QR code.

Is the idea to print the QRCode (with the text) on paper, which will then be affixed to the pot? If so, you could add the images (and their corresponding texts) to a webpage (HTML) and print that out on paper

You can create another blank image with taller height than the QR code image (using Pillow.Image module) and paste the QR code image onto the top side of the blank image and draw the required text at the bottom of the blank image.

I'd caution against having a variable in the qr function that's also named qr (or really any variable inside any function that shares the name of the function)

You can use Spire.Barcode for Python module to generate a QR code image with text.
pip install Spire.Barcode

Here is a code example:
from spire.barcode import *

# Create a BarcodeSettings object
barcodeSettings = BarcodeSettings()
# Set the barcode type as QR code
barcodeSettings.Type = BarCodeType.QRCode
# Set the data of the QR code 
barcodeSettings.Data = "12345ABCDE"
barcodeSettings.Data2D = "12345ABCDE"
# Set the width of the QR code bar module
barcodeSettings.X = 3
# Set the error correction level of the QR code
barcodeSettings.QRCodeECL = QRCodeECL.M

# Set the top and bottom text 
barcodeSettings.TopText = "Top Text"
barcodeSettings.TopTextColor = Color.get_Blue()
barcodeSettings.BottomText = "Bottom Text"
barcodeSettings.BottomTextColor = Color.get_Blue()

# Set text visibility
barcodeSettings.ShowText = False
barcodeSettings.ShowTopText = True
barcodeSettings.ShowBottomText = True

# Create a BarCodeGenerator object with the specified settings
barCodeGenerator = BarCodeGenerator(barcodeSettings)
# Generate QR code image
barcodeimage = barCodeGenerator.GenerateImage()

# Save the QR code image to a .png file
with open("QRCodeWithText.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(barcodeimage)

Here is the result:

For more details, you can check this blog: How to Generate QR Codes in Python (A Comprehensive Guide)
Note: I work for the company that developed this module.
